# How to close off a section not to get Ngon modelling with subsurface modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I've got a section of a mesh I'm practicing with subdivision modifier and topology. I'm left with one vertex and I can't figure out how to close off the topology with quads, I cannot go outside the red border, it has to be done within or else I'd cut right through. And also I'd like to know if my topology is correct making quads.

[image]

Comment: Hey :). Why not just [put a loopcut there](https://imgur.com/a/2nvMDeA), just like on the opposite side? Seems like the cleanest solution :).

Comment: _and_ you could then model under a mirror in X

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the feedback, I was hoping not to take the easy way out, I know that if I perform a straight cut through I call it a day, but I'm following a tutorial how to make quads on the mesh, so as I was improvising I came across what I posted. So if possible I'd like another method so I can get more insight and skills on topology.

I'm 1000% sure this would be the best solution, but I'd like a more theoretical approach.

https://ibb.co/h2CqF7K

Comment: Hello :). For theoretical exercises try https://topologyguides.com/loop-reduction

Comment: You've solved the other identical sections with a loop cut in the middle, and on the bottom part of the mesh there is already another loopcut. Just extend the cut right in the middle of the object as suggested by @JachymMichal

Comment: Those U turn techniques https://i.imgur.com/Twd0uUH.png are nice when you can't add a loopcut, or adding a loopcut would add a lot of geometry (increase the number of faces a lot), which doesn't happen here. So loopcuts would create a more logical flow with nearly the same number of faces. https://i.imgur.com/1Vk74vE.png

Comment: In the example, I have made a multitude of holes in a mesh, there are ngongs using this method, but the result is clean since its not a spherical object, and causes no bad shading, so would this be considered ok since its a flat surface? https://ibb.co/1s0GqK1

Comment: If an ngon is planar, and you can be assured that it will stay planar (for example it will not be animated or bent around a curve, etc) the appearance will be fine, and that's probably the most important part.